# How did the "fragile" option in Beamer get its name?

Tags: beamer, tex-history

`fragile` is an indispensable option in beamer presentations. However I never understood nor was able to find much information about how it got its name, which seems quite peculiar.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands

Comment: Not all slides are `fragile`. I've to use it with `listings` or `verbatim` contents. It means that the content is not `robust` enough and need to be `protected`.

Comment: From the beameruserguide: "You must also use the [fragile] option for frames that include any “fragile” text, which is any text that is not “interpreted the way text is usually interpreted by TEX.” For example, if you use a package that (locally) redefined the meaning of, say, the character &, you must use this option."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I see. I thought it's a Beamer specific thing.

Comment: Actually I think this fragile is different from the normal "fragile" thing (i.e. **the duplicate closure is wrong**). This one also protect against catcode-changing, normal \protect does not.